# excel: charting with unknown number of data

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Let's (for discussion purposes) say that I have x and y data in 2 columns. They're some measured data which, several times a day, a few of them are added (usually 4 times a day).
Now, I wish to plot y=f(x) (linear scale), but the problem is since data is constantly added to determine the number of points which will go in the plot. Always creating a new plot and then formatting it and all, is troublesome for ... reasons.

Is there a way to do this using excel's build in functions ? Should I use vba ? I tried googling, but I don't know what to search for. I'd appreciate any help on this, even if its just a point in the right direction.

Is there a way to tell excel, use all points in this column until you hit an empty cell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without any VBA. Jon Peltier has an example by Debra Dalgleish on his website:

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html

It can be pretty frustrating to Google anything related to Excel because there is so much junk out there, but I've found that if there's something "obvious" that you know shouldn't be so hard, one of the various "MVP" sites will have covered it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. "dynamic column chart" - yep, I never would have guessed that. Thanks !

Comment: I have to assume that this sudden uncommented downvote on a nine-month old post is some kind of tit-for-tat thing...

Comment: And I know that this second uncommented downvote on a now almost two-year old post is...but I'm going to continue leaving comments and outing myself when I downvote.

Comment: +1 for reversing the uncommented downvote :) `but I'm going to continue leaving comments and outing myself when I downvote. – jtolle` That my dear friend is a very positive approach. :)